# Azure App Service Error 500 after App Service Plan change

Tags: .net, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-service-plans, azure-service-plan

I'm completely new to Azure App Services, but I've managed to build a first test application (using a free test Service Plan) with .NET backend. Now that this worked fine, I decided to upgrade and go for a Basic Service Plan. After doing so in the Azure Portal, I tried to retrieve data via my client application and Postman but all I got was "500 internal server error" with the vacuous error message "An error has occurred". The strange thing is, though, that if I start debugging locally, everything is working fine and I can access all resources.

Edit
As evilSnobu suggested I turned on Failed Request Tracing and I was getting following error:

```
System.ApplicationException: The trace listener AzureBlobTraceListener is disabled. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The SAS URL for the cloud storage account is not specified. Use the environment variable 'DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL' to define it.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.RefreshConfig()
```

After setting the storage account in the diagnostic logs as described in the answer to [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102410/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-storageexception-the-remote-server-returned-an-e), I'm getting following error:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockList(IEnumerable`1 blockList, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.AppendStreamToBlob(Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.ConsumeBuffer()
Request Information
StatusMessage:The specified block list is invalid.
ErrorCode:InvalidBlockList
```

Has anybody got a solution for this?

Comment: Did you try to restart your Web App from the portal blade? The Restart button will trigger an app pool recycle for a .NET app.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that

Comment: Turn on Failed Request Tracing from Diagnostics logs in the Portal, then browse through the traces see what's triggering the 500s.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I created my azure mobile app to test this scenario. I deployed my web application to azure app service without enable the diagnostic logging. After scaling up to the higher tier, I could access my table endpoint via the browser. I recommend that you could leverage [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) to empty your web content files under `D:\home\site\wwwroot` to narrow this issue. Also, you could try to scale up your plan to a lower tier or create a new web app under your basic service plan and deploy your application again to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: I ended up creating a new app - everything's working fine again