# twilio c# sdk publish to azure app service

Tags: twilio, azure-web-app-service

Downloaded Twilio C# SDK for chat application and when I run off Visual Studio -- it works fine (localhost:port).

Now I would like to publish this on to Azure App Service.  Running into issues here.  Hope someone can give me pointers.

```
1>------ Publish started: Project: TwilioSdkStarterDotnetCore.Web, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Web App was published successfully http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I think the problem is Twilio has external URL in the code that Azure does not like.  Not sure.  Even if it is, not sure how to fix.

ERROR:
    System.ApplicationException: The trace listener AzureBlobTraceListener is disabled. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The SAS URL for the cloud storage account is not specified. Use the environment variable 'DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL' to define it.
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.RefreshConfig()

```
From Azure App Service log stream:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Connecting...
2019-01-03T20:09:36  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.

2019-01-03T20:09:50

System.ApplicationException: The trace listener AzureBlobTraceListener is disabled. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The SAS URL for the cloud storage account is not specified. Use the environment variable 'DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL' to define it.

   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.RefreshConfig()

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---



2019-01-03T20:09:50  PID[4536] Information VSProjectId: 79a347a8-313a-4d83-8c0c-7fe1cba0aa67

2019-01-03T20:09:50  PID[4536] Information DeploymentComplete

2019-01-03 20:09:54.706 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Hosting starting

2019-01-03 20:09:54.794 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager: Azure Web Sites environment detected. Using 'D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.

2019-01-03 20:09:54.834 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository: Reading data from file 'D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\key-3205a103-24e9-43f7-b49c-c3d6f8f8c36f.xml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:54.959 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Internal.DataProtectionStartupFilter: Key ring with default key {3205a103-24e9-43f7-b49c-c3d6f8f8c36f} was loaded during application startup.

2019-01-03 20:09:54.987 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions: Compatibility switch AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages in type MvcJsonOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1

2019-01-03 20:09:55.000 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions: Compatibility switch AllowCombiningAuthorizeFilters in type MvcOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1

2019-01-03 20:09:55.000 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions: Compatibility switch AllowBindingHeaderValuesToNonStringModelTypes in type MvcOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1

2019-01-03 20:09:55.000 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions: Compatibility switch AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes in type MvcOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1

2019-01-03 20:09:55.000 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions: Compatibility switch InputFormatterExceptionPolicy in type MvcOptions is using compatibility value MalformedInputExceptions for version Version_2_1


2019-01-03 20:09:55.117 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBinderFactory: Registered model binder providers, in the following order: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BinderTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ServicesModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.HeaderModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FloatingPointTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.EnumTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.CancellationTokenModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ByteArrayModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormFileModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormCollectionModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.KeyValuePairModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.DictionaryModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ArrayModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.CollectionModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinderProvider

2019-01-03 20:09:55.177 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer: Failed to locate the development https certificate at '(null)'.

2019-01-03 20:09:55.313 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Hosting started

2019-01-03 20:09:55.313 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Loaded hosting startup assembly TwilioSdkStarterDotnetCore.Web

2019-01-03 20:09:55.313 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Loaded hosting startup assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.HostingStartup

2019-01-03 20:09:55.313 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Loaded hosting startup assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration

2019-01-03 20:09:55.386 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Connection id "0HLJHMTMRPB3K" started.

2019-01-03 20:09:55.501 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets: Connection id "0HLJHMTMRPB3K" received FIN.

2019-01-03 20:09:55.511 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Connection id "0HLJHMTMRPB3K" disconnecting.

2019-01-03 20:09:55.532 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets: Connection id "0HLJHMTMRPB3K" sending FIN.

2019-01-03 20:09:55.543 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Connection id "0HLJHMTMRPB3K" stopped.

2019-01-03 20:09:55.574 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Connection id "0HLJHMTMRPB3L" started.

2019-01-03 20:09:55.632 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;} 
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} 
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} 
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} 
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} 
a:hover{text-decoration:none;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} 
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;} 
h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0; 
}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif; 
color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2; 
}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} 
.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} 
.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0; 
}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%; 
}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden; 
}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF; 
background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal; 
font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right; 
}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;} 
table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;} 
td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;} 
th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;} 
thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%; 
}#details-right th{width:20%;} 
table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{} 
.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;} 
.clear{clear:both;} 
.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;} 
--> 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<h3>HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found</h3> 
<h4>The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h4> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.</li>  <li>The URL contains a typographical error.</li>    <li>A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.</li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>Create the content on the Web server.</li>  <li>Review the browser URL.</li>    <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> 
<div id="details-left"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AspNetCoreModule</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;aspNetCore</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000000</td></tr> 

</table> 
</div> 
<div id="details-right"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:80/</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D:\home\site\wwwroot</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr> 

</table> 
<div class="clear"></div> 
</div> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4> 
This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request again. 
<p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=404,0,0x00000000,14393">View more information &raquo;</a></p> 
<p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p> 


</fieldset> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html> 
2019-01-03 20:09:55.633 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware: Wildcard detected, all requests with hosts will be allowed.

2019-01-03 20:09:55.640 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware: All hosts are allowed.

2019-01-03 20:09:55.659 +00:00 [Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware: Failed to determine the https port for redirect.

2019-01-03 20:09:55.680 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: The request path / does not match a supported file type

2019-01-03 20:09:55.959 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase: Request successfully matched the route with name 'default' and template '{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}'.

2019-01-03 20:09:55.999 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing action TwilioSdkStarterDotnetCore.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index (TwilioSdkStarterDotnetCore.Web)

2019-01-03 20:09:56.005 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Execution plan of authorization filters (in the following order): None

2019-01-03 20:09:56.005 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Execution plan of resource filters (in the following order): Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter

2019-01-03 20:09:56.005 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Execution plan of action filters (in the following order): Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionFilter (Order: -2147483648), Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter

2019-01-03 20:09:56.005 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Execution plan of exception filters (in the following order): None

2019-01-03 20:09:56.005 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Execution plan of result filters (in the following order): Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter

2019-01-03 20:09:56.007 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Resource Filter: Before executing OnResourceExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.007 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Resource Filter: After executing OnResourceExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.018 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Action Filter: Before executing OnActionExecutionAsync on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.027 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Action Filter: Before executing OnActionExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.027 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Action Filter: After executing OnActionExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.037 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executing action method TwilioSdkStarterDotnetCore.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index (TwilioSdkStarterDotnetCore.Web) - Validation state: Valid

2019-01-03 20:09:56.045 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action method TwilioSdkStarterDotnetCore.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index (TwilioSdkStarterDotnetCore.Web), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in 0.4307ms.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.045 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Action Filter: Before executing OnActionExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.045 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Action Filter: After executing OnActionExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.UnsupportedContentTypeFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.045 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Action Filter: After executing OnActionExecutionAsync on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.046 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Result Filter: Before executing OnResultExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.046 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Result Filter: After executing OnResultExecuting on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.048 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Before executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.057 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine: View lookup cache miss for view 'Index' in controller 'Home'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.058 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Initializing Razor view compiler with compiled view: '/Views/Chat/Index.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.058 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Initializing Razor view compiler with compiled view: '/Views/Home/Index.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.058 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Initializing Razor view compiler with compiled view: '/Views/Notify/Index.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.058 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Initializing Razor view compiler with compiled view: '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.058 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Initializing Razor view compiler with compiled view: '/Views/Shared/_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.058 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Initializing Razor view compiler with compiled view: '/Views/Sync/Index.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.058 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Initializing Razor view compiler with compiled view: '/Views/Video/Index.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.064 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Initializing Razor view compiler with compiled view: '/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.064 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Initializing Razor view compiler with compiled view: '/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.065 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Located compiled view for view at path '/Views/Home/Index.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.075 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Could not find a file for view at path '/Views/Home/_ViewStart.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.075 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Located compiled view for view at path '/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.077 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Could not find a file for view at path '/_ViewStart.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.077 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine: Using precompiled view for '/Views/Home/Index.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.084 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor: Executing ViewResult, running view Index.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.085 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor: The view path '/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' was found in 28.1834ms.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.214 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine: View lookup cache miss for view '_Layout' in controller 'Home'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.214 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Could not find a file for view at path '/Views/Home/_Layout.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.214 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler: Located compiled view for view at path '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.215 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine: Using precompiled view for '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.335 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: After executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.336 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Result Filter: Before executing OnResultExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.336 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Result Filter: After executing OnResultExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.336 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Resource Filter: Before executing OnResourceExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.336 +00:00 [Trace] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Resource Filter: After executing OnResourceExecuted on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.SaveTempDataFilter.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.336 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action TwilioSdkStarterDotnetCore.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index (TwilioSdkStarterDotnetCore.Web) in 330.8858ms

2019-01-03 20:09:56.412 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml': 'Styles'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

2019-01-03 20:09:56.414 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: The request path /Home/Error does not match a supported file type

2019-01-03 20:09:56.414 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase: Request successfully matched the route with name 'default' and template '{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}'.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.422 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector: No actions matched the current request. Route values: controller=Home, action=Error

2019-01-03 20:09:56.422 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcRouteHandler: No actions matched the current request. Route values: controller=Home, action=Error

2019-01-03 20:09:56.422 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware: Request did not match any routes.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.425 +00:00 [Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Connection id "0HLJHMTMRPB3L" completed keep alive response.

2019-01-03 20:09:56.441 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 810.0333ms 404 

2019-01-03 20:08:57 xxxxxxxxxxxx GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=e9cbd7fd-3276-4c70-bf95-0acdd80e637e 80 - 13.13.16.2 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/58.0.3029.110+Safari/537.36+Edge/16.16299 - - xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net 404 0 0 328 999 3533

2019-01-03 20:09:28 ~1xxxxxxxxxxxx GET /api/vfs/site/wwwroot/ _=1546546158817&X-ARR-LOG-ID=e63305a7-9618-48d7-ab3b-2c3c716ff36b 443 - 13.13.137.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:64.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/64.0 - https://websites.hosting.portal.azure.net/websites?bundlingKind=PopularPartitioner&cacheability=3&extensionName=WebsitesExtension&l=en&pageVersion=5.12.34.339&trustedAuthority=portal.azure.com xxxxxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 2373 1643 514

2019-01-03 20:09:48 ~1xxxxxxxxxxxx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=xxxxxxxxxxxx&X-ARR-LOG-ID=4ed97fa0-1c03-4ec2-a2be-0eb145b6841a 443 - 13.13.157.6 - - - xxxxxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 412 1077 19

2019-01-03 20:09:48 ~1xxxxxxxxxxxx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=xxxxxxxxxxxx&X-ARR-LOG-ID=16d097ec-fb4d-461c-ac12-920ea317561f 443 - 13.13.157.6 - ARRAffinity=69e56d94bc2631bcc7dd44f6f455e6e654512fd223067d328f88fbea76b6ea85 - xxxxxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 412 1165 9

2019-01-03 20:09:48 ~1xxxxxxxxxxxx POST /msdeploy.axd site=xxxxxxxxxxxx&X-ARR-LOG-ID=c55ecae7-4bea-4354-aaad-a5f33679a35e 443 - 13.13.157.6 VSCmdLine:WTE2.1.500.1853;sid=1b9a629a-5f37-4ffb-846d-c2f79ec96757;op=Sync ARRAffinity=69e56d94bc2631bcc7dd44f6f455e6e654512fd223067d328f88fbea76b6ea85 - xxxxxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 767 14711 382

2019-01-03 20:09:48 ~1xxxxxxxxxxxx POST /msdeploy.axd site=xxxxxxxxxxxx&X-ARR-LOG-ID=3b31d177-31c9-4b5e-8004-f3d285bbda0d 443 - 13.13.157.6 - ARRAffinity=69e56d94bc2631bcc7dd44f6f455e6e654512fd223067d328f88fbea76b6ea85 - xxxxxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 503 1273 885

2019-01-03 20:09:49 ~1xxxxxxxxxxxx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=xxxxxxxxxxxx&X-ARR-LOG-ID=03a0ab1a-c8c9-439b-b7d9-6a0c31f2746f 443 - 13.13.157.6 - ARRAffinity=69e56d94bc2631bcc7dd44f6f455e6e654512fd223067d328f88fbea76b6ea85 - xxxxxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 412 1163 15

2019-01-03 20:09:49 ~1xxxxxxxxxxxx POST /msdeploy.axd site=xxxxxxxxxxxx&X-ARR-LOG-ID=ded7df79-b97b-4405-88b7-50cc17ab652b 443 - 13.13.157.6 - ARRAffinity=69e56d94bc2631bcc7dd44f6f455e6e654512fd223067d328f88fbea76b6ea85 - xxxxxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 957 1275 757
```

Comment: Not familiar with twilio. But you can take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102410/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-storageexception-the-remote-server-returned-an-e), the same error message with yours.

Comment: It seems to be complaining mid way through that log that a `Styles` section doesn't exist. Have you edited the views at all? Also, the above comment is fair too, have you looked into solving the SAS URL issue?

Comment: A tangential suggestion that may solve your problem - push to a private github repo, and setup continuous deployment in your app service. The azure side will handle the build, and may resolve whatever build issues you're seeing.

There are some problems with VS2017 Azure integration.