# Azure blob storage account return error (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-account

i am getting error when uploading excel file on azure storage account,
please suggest how can i solve this problem.

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)

```
public long UploadFile( string containerName, string fileName, string mediaType, Stream fileContents )
    {       
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"];
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse( connectionString ); 
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference( containerName.ToLowerInvariant() );
        if( container.CreateIfNotExists() )
        {
        }

        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference( fileName );
        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = mediaType;

        blockBlob.UploadFromStream( fileContents );

        return blockBlob.Properties.Length;
    }

<add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccountname;AccountKey=Key" />
```

Comment: A 403 suggests that you are not authorized to make the request. Check your credentials/keys. Otherwise, you’ll need to explain a lot more as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: thanks you @KJ3 for your suggestion,
i also verified my keys, its working on testing and staging server but its not working on production server

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: hi @GauravMantri i am shared code, please check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (403)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102410/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-storageexception-the-remote-server-returned-an-e)

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. You mentioned that the code works in testing/staging but not in production server. By these environment do you mean web server i.e. you're able to uploading file when this code runs in your testing/staging web server or do you have separate accounts for each environment and you can upload in testing/staging storage account but not production storage account?