# Getting Error while configuring App Service logs for Storage Containers to see the log stream

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

getting below error in the log stream:

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)--- End of inner exception stack trace ---at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.AppendStreamToBlob(Stream stream)at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.ConsumeBuffer()Request InformationRequestID:021a82f5-601e-003b-34cc-c1cb82000000RequestDate:Tue, 06 Sep 2022 08:39:48 GMTStatusMessage:This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.ErrorCode:AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch

Thanks
Ramesh

Comment: what is the framework version are you using? also how you have deployed your webapp?

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 deploying in App Service

Comment: The issue is with SAS certificate while generating from Azure it's working fine, 

but i am using Bicep file to generate from infrastrucuture and its not working:-
var appLogs = {
  canonicalizedResource: '/blob/${infraName}/${BlobContainer}'
  signedResourceTypes: 'c'
  signedversion: 'sv'
  signedPermission: 'rwdl' 
  signedServices: 'b'
  signedExpiry: '2299-01-01T00:00:00Z'  
}

Comment: This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102410/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-storageexception-the-remote-server-returned-an-e) will help.